# iOS-FFmpeg-Compose video from audio and image files

Tags: ios, audio, ffmpeg, video-streaming, video-processing

I am working in a iOS project that using FFmpeg library for video processing. And I got a task for composing video from audio file and a set of image files.
Have anyone experienced on similar task?
Help me please!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SwiftVideoGenerator`
use Cocoapods to install `SwiftVideoGenerator`, you need to import the module:

```
import SwiftVideoGenerator
```

Create a video from multiple images and a single audio

```
if let audioURL1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: Audio1, withExtension: Mp3Extension) {
  LoadingView.lockView()

  VideoGenerator.current.fileName = MultipleSingleMovieFileName
  VideoGenerator.current.shouldOptimiseImageForVideo = true

  VideoGenerator.current.generate(withImages: [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image1"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image2"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image3"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "image4")], andAudios: [audioURL1], andType: .singleAudioMultipleImage, { (progress) in
    print(progress)
  }, success: { (url) in
    LoadingView.unlockView()
    print(url)
    self.createAlertView(message: self.FnishedMultipleVideoGeneration)
  }, failure: { (error) in
    LoadingView.unlockView()
    print(error)
    self.createAlertView(message: error.localizedDescription)
  })
} else {
  self.createAlertView(message: MissingAudioFiles)
}
```

for reference visit : https://github.com/dev-labs-bg/swift-video-generator

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But I expect to generate video by using the FFmpeg library. Other libraries won't be accepted.

Comment: No one know hơ to compose images and audio into video by FFmpeg, right?

Comment: Your solution is great but I want to handle the task by using FFmpeg purely